NoSuchElementException error of the Selenium WebDriver
I'm having trouble with my Selenium WebDriver project in VB.NET. I'm currently trying to simulate human operation on playing web video process. Just trying to explore how the Selenium WebDriver can automize the process.
The code is trying to play the YouTube video for approximately 40 seconds, but if there's an ad before the video, I want the program to wait for 10 seconds and then click the "Skip ad" button to skip the ad and play the video normally. And if there's no ad, I want it to play the video directly. That what we usually did when we are watching any youtube videos.
But, what I've found is that the program will be in error when there's no ad before the video. The program will fail to locate the Skip ads button on screen. I am trying to catch the NoSuchElementException with a Try-Catch block, but it's not working as expected.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
Imports System.Threading
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Edge
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Setup EdgeOptions
        Dim options As New EdgeOptions()
        options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=C:\Users\jasonfan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data")
        options.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-pipe")
        options.AddArgument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
        options.AddArgument("log-level=3")

        Dim driver As IWebDriver = New EdgeDriver(options)

        Try
            Dim index As Integer = 0

            Do While index <= 5
                'Navigate to the URL of a youtube video
                '****This is just a testing example. It could be any youtube video.****
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnpyIbK-Y78")

                ' Wait for the ad skip button to appear (if present)
                Dim adSkipButtonFound As Boolean = False
                Try
                    Dim wait As New WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
                    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(GetType(NoSuchElementException))
                    Dim adSkipButton As IWebElement = wait.Until(Function(d) d.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ytp-skip-ad-button")))
                    adSkipButtonFound = True
                    ' If ad skip button appears, wait for 10 seconds and click it
                    Thread.Sleep(10000)
                    adSkipButton.Click()
                Catch ex As WebDriverTimeoutException
                    ' No ad skip button present, let the video play
                    MessageBox.Show("No ad skip button found, letting video play.")
                End Try

                ' Wait for the video to finish playing (approximately 40 seconds)
                Thread.Sleep(40000) ' Adjusted to 40 seconds

                index += 1
            Loop
        Catch ex As WebDriverException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Clean up
            driver.Quit()
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' Define a function to get a random delay
    Private Function RandomDelay() As Integer
        Dim rnd As New Random()
        Return rnd.Next(1000, 3000) ' Random delay between 1 and 2 seconds
    End Function
End Class

I've ensured that both the WebDriver and Edge browser are up to date. Is there any additional configuration or setting I might be missing?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
(By the way, I'm currently using Windows 11 platform. Both my version of Microsoft Edge and WebDriver are 128.0.2739.42)
I have tried and tried again. It always got stuck on this line:
Dim adSkipButton As IWebElement = wait.Until(Function(d) d.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ytp-skip-ad-button")))
And the visual studio 2019 always gave me this error message:
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ytp-skip-ad-button"}
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=128.0.2739.63); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception


The issue with your code is likely due to the WebDriverWait not being handled correctly in the Try-Catch block. Specifically, the code inside the Try block will always execute, and the Catch block may not handle the case where the adSkipButton is not found properly.
To fix the issue, you should ensure that the Try block waits for the ad skip button to appear and only proceeds if it is found, and handles the scenario where it is not found.
Here is corrected script
Dim adSkipButtonFound As Boolean = False
Dim wait As New WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
Try       
    Dim adSkipButton As IWebElement = wait.Until(Function(d) d.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ytp-skip-ad-button")))
    adSkipButtonFound = True
    Thread.Sleep(10000)
    adSkipButton.Click()
Catch ex As WebDriverTimeoutException      
    MessageBox.Show("No ad skip button found, letting video play.")
End Try


I just tested it. It does not work at all.
As expected, the first time when there's an ads, it waited for 10 seconds and clicked the adSkipButton. And then, the video will play.
After the video has played for 40 seconds, it reloaded. This time, when there's no ads, the program failed at the line: Dim adSkipButton As IWebElement = wait.Until(Function(d) d.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ytp-skip-ad-button")))
And the program error is 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' again.
I still have no idea why this happen. Actually, you can test on any youtube video. It could happen to any video.

Then You can simple use try: and except:
rather than trying to catch if it is not working perfectly

Actually I did already last week. But I just want to find out why this catch will cause the OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException error. I want to know the reason why and how to solve it perfectly. Is it a bug?
